# Поиск кнопки по id

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть несколько кнопок, как кнопке с `id=28` присвоить класс `edit`?

```
<button data-id="28" class="button add get_list">Выбрать</button>
<button data-id="29" class="button add get_list">Выбрать</button>
<button data-id="30" class="button add get_list">Выбрать</button>
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Comment: это я знаю, а если мне известен только id, например 28 и этой кнопки добавить класс

Comment: Вы упорно говорите про `id`, хотя в вопросе написано `data-id`.

Comment: я его и имею ввиду, пробовал так, но что-то не то
var elem = $(".constructor .result_category .add").attr("data-id").values(28);
elem.toggleClass('edit');

Comment: У jquery есть метод `filter`. Или через `selector`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(".constructor .result_category .add[data-id='28']").toggleClass('edit');
```

или

```
$(".constructor .result_category .add").each(function() {
  if ($(this).data("id") == 28) {
    $(this).toggleClass('edit'); 
  }    
});
```

или (спасибо, @And)

```
$(".constructor .result_category .add").
  filter(function() { return $(this).data("id") == 28; }).toggleClass('edit');
```